# MISRA C 2012 Rule 15.4 and replacing goto's with break's

Tags: c, misra

Regarding to MISRA C 2012 rule 15.4 - "There should be no more than one break or goto statement used to terminate any iteration statement." - is this example correct? Can anyone confirm this with some tool (MISRA checker)?

```
do {
    retval = do_smth();
    if (retval != OK) {
        break;
    }

    retval = do_smth2();
    if (retval != OK) {
        break;
    }

    retval = do_smth3();
} while (0u);
```

This is just a concept, but what I am trying here is to replace cascade of `goto` (unfortunately banned in this case) with cascade of `break`. My point is that `do { } while(0u);` is not an iteration statement.
What you think?

Comment: A `do`-`while` loop is still an iteration statement, regardless of whether the condition ensures there'll only be one iteration.

Comment: What's the context? Is this inside a macro declaration or something, or why are you otherwise using do-while(0)?

Comment: @Lundin: I think earlier code used several `goto`s (to the same label) and the `do`/`while` is used here to achieve the same behaviour with `break`s.

Comment: Exactly as @MOehm said. The context is described in the question below the code example.

Comment: Quite aside from whether a run-once loop qualifies as "iteration" or not, the code in question is *less* readable and *more* confusing than what it replaced, so it cannot be justified as part of an exercise that was supposed to ensure readability, reliability, and maintainability.

Comment: MISRA C:2012 permits the use of forward `goto`s - so I would suggest you retain those rather than trying to concoct a (claimed) other conformant mechanism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your code does indeed not follow rule 15.4 since you have 3 `break` inside an iteration statement<sup>1)</sup>. But it is just an advisory one and there's nothing wrong with using multiple breaks like you do as long as the code is readable and easy to follow.

The main rationale with these MISRA rules is to prevent "compound statement spaghetti" where complex code breaks out from multiple nested compound statements. It's important to understand the rationale before following these rules blindly. So in this case just consider leaving the code as it is - no deviation is needed for advisory rules.

Otherwise, there's a few options as shown below:

---

One problem with MISRA-C is that it doesn't allow multiple returns from a function, even when it makes the code more readable. Otherwise the obvious and most readable solution would be to use a function:

```
type do_stuff (void);
{
  type retval;

  retval = do_smth();
  if (retval != OK) { return retval; }

  retval = do_smth2();
  if (retval != OK) { return retval; }

  retval = do_smth3();

  return retval;
}
```

My usual solution is to make a permanent MISRA-C deviation from the multiple return rule and allow it in cases where it makes the code *more* readable, like it does in this case.

Otherwise, the 2nd best option might be the old "on error goto" - the rule banning `goto` was relaxed in MISRA-C:2012 so it's just advisory now.

```
  retval = do_smth();
  if (retval != OK) { goto error; }

  retval = do_smth2();
  if (retval != OK) { goto error; }

  retval = do_smth3();
  if (retval != OK) { goto error; }

  goto everything_ok;

  error:
    /* error handling */

  everything_ok:
```

If neither of the above forms are OK because you are super-strict with MISRA-C, then the 3rd option might be something like this, which I believe is 100% MISRA-C compliant:

```
typedef type do_stuff_t (void);

do_stuff_t* const do_stuff[N] = { do_smth, do_smth2, do_smth3 };
type retval = OK;

for(uint32_t i=0u; (i<N) && (retval==OK); i++)
{
  retval = do_stuff[i]();
}
```

---

> My point is that do { } while(0u); is not an iteration statement.

The C language disagrees with you.

<sup>1)</sup> From C17:

> 6.8.5 Iteration statements
>
> Syntax
>
> *iteration-statement:*
> `while` `(` *expression* `)` *statement*
> `do` *statement* `while` `(` *expression* `) ;`

Comment: Hearty, hearty agreement on the "understand the rationale before following these rules blindly", "one problem is that it doesn't allow multiple returns even when it makes the code more readable", and "make a permanent deviation and allow it in cases where it makes the code *more* readable" points.  It just kills me when too-strict adherence to too-strict rules leads directly to code that is less readable, reliable, or maintainable.

Comment: I accept this answer as you refereed to C standard to prove your point. Personally I would choose a 2nd option, as I find that having a single return point improve readability and is helpful during debugging... but that's another story.

Comment: @SteveSummit "understand the rationale before following these rules blindly" As far as I know, the MISRA-C committee also strongly agree with this (or at least individual members do each time I speak to one) - they named the document _guidelines_ for a reason. However, I wrote the function pointer version since it might have a few other benefits namely centralized maintenance. This code is actually a finite state machine in its simplest form.

Comment: @radoslav006 I think each of these 3 are fine, though the 1st and 2nd (as well as your original) violate various _advisory_ rules. But it's the _required_ rules you need to be extra picky with.

Comment: "understand the rationale before following these rules blindly".  Correct.  And if need be, use a Deviation (we defined that process for a reason!) [Disclaimer... see profile for affiliation!]

Answer (score 5):

I'd replace your code with this:

```
  retval = do_smth();
  if (retval == OK) {
    retval = do_smth2();
  } 
  if (retval == OK) {
    retval = do_smth3();
  }
```

- no phony while
- no gotos disguised as break
- hence not even a single goto/break
- hence no more MISRA issues
- bonus: half the number of lines than in the original code

BTW: the last break (`break; // <- 3rd`) was useless anyway

Comment: While this looks neat in this particular example, this will become burdensome and needlessly slow in case of extensive error checking. Keep in mind that in case of failure the program still has to execute a bunch of `if (retval == OK)` branches, which isn't ideal.

Comment: I know that I can make it shorter that way - I already do that, but three things here:
1. Your code is not 1:1 equivalent as you need to do all checks in whole cascade, in case of `break`or `goto` you can immediatly return.  
2. This example is simple, but sometimes it gets more complicated.  
3. Anyway, this not answer my question.

Answer (score 4):

> There should be no more than one break or goto statement used to terminate any iteration statement.

Your example has 3 breaks in one do-while (iteration statement), so it is not correct I think. A `break` is a control-flow/loop-control statement and is only valid in the context of a loop. I don't think your argument is valid here, though I see where you're going.

TL;DR: `do-while` is still an iteration statement, even though it only runs once.

```
do {
    retval = do_smth();
    if (retval != OK) {
        break; // <- 1st
    }

    retval = do_smth2();
    if (retval != OK) {
        break;  // <- 2nd
    }
    retval = do_smth3();
    if (retval != OK) {
        break; // <- 3rd
    }
} while (0u);
```

Comment: I will argue with that - if something runs always once, there is no iteration by definition. But more important here is what the MISRA compliance tools think, I am very curious about that.

Comment: @radoslav006 it requires static analysis to determine how many times a do-while loops - because it IS a loop-construction by definition - you will not argue with that I hope. In the general case, you cannot determine the loop bounds statically. However you can often do so conservatively.

Comment: @radoslav006 Iteration statement is a formal term in standard C. `while` and `do...while` are iteration statements. No matter the amount of iterations. I added a quote from the standard to my answer.

Comment: @radoslav006 *I will argue with that - if something runs always once, there is no iteration by definition.* And that attitude is problematic - you are looking for ways to weasel around the standard you are being paid to write code to.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's your opinion (and not helpful at all to be honest); in my opinion I am looking for ways to **be compliant** with the standard **and** to not write a horrible spaghetti code. MISRA is ok, but the problems comes when one enforce to apply all the MISRA rules - the created code is no more nice and clean and MISRA says it by itself (e.g. in rule 15.1).

Comment: @radoslav006 You literally tried to claim `do { ... } while()` is not an iteration statement.  That's **objectively** looking for ways to subvert the standard you are being paid to write code to: "I'll claim this C code isn't what the C standard **defines** it as in order to get around this MISRA rule."  That's not trying to be compliant.  That's like telling the police officer who pulled you over for speeding, "My going 38 in a 25 isn't really speeding because the sign on the other side of the road for vehicles going the other way says 40 mph and the road is the same in both directions."

Comment: @AndrewHenle stick with the facts:
1. I didn't anywhere ever suggest that `do { ... } while()` is not an iteration statement. I suggest that `do { ... } while(0u)` is not an iteration statement - there is a difference.
2. I didn't try to convince anyone that I am right, I just asked **if** I am right. So the example with police officer is wrong.
That's all from me in this discussion.

Comment: @radoslav006 Wow.  You're ***still*** trying to subvert MISRA:  "1. I didn't anywhere ever suggest that `do { ... } while()` is not an iteration statement. I suggest that `do { ... } while(0u)` is not an iteration statement - there is a difference."  No, there is no difference - a `do {...} while()` ***is*** an iteration statement.  You're ***still*** playing, "If I twist the meaning of this, I don't have to code to the standard I'm being paid to code to." That's subverting the standard. You also apparently need to read the [Law of Holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_holes).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this code is good enough. It works though.

```
switch(0) {
default:
    retval = do_smth();
    if (retval != OK) {
        break;
    }

    retval = do_smth2();
    if (retval != OK) {
        break;
    }

    retval = do_smth3();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: or just switch(0) {
    retval = do_smth();
    if (retval != OK) {
        break;
    }

    retval = do_smth2();
    if (retval != OK) {
        break;
    }

    retval = do_smth3();
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on MISRA, so this may be forbidden for other reasons, but in this situation I might be tempted to use something like this:

```
if((retval = do_smth()) != OK)
    ;
else if((retval = do_smth2()) != OK)
    ;
else if((retval = do_smth3()) != OK)
    ;
```

No `goto`, no `break`, no iteration, no duplicated tests.

The empty statements look weird, it's true, although in practice, there will often be some error-logging code to put there.  If naked semicolons aren't to your taste, you could use `{ }`, or `{ /* do nothing */ }`.

Assignments inside conditionals (as in the classic `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)` loop) can be confusing to the novice (and I suspect MISRA probably bans them for more or less that reason), but in many cases, if you can tolerate them, they can really help to make various other uglinesses melt away.

Comment: MISRA-C doesn't allow assignment inside selection statements, as another advisory rule 13.4 "the result of an assignment operator should not be used". The rationale is "can significantly impair the readability of the code" but also "It introduces additional side effects into a statement making it more difficult to avoid undefined behavior". Consider for example `retval = do_smth(retval)` which is somewhat subtle UB.

Comment: In addition, MISRA-C requires else-if chains to end with a final `else`, which in this case would just be a `else ;`. That's a required rule, so considered more important. The rationale being defensive programming in this case.

Comment: However, this code should be 100% MISRA-C compliant: `if(do_smth(&retval) != OK)
    ;
else if(do_smth2(&retval) != OK)
    ;
else if(do_smth3(&retval) != OK)
    ;
else
    ;`  So if changing the function is an option, that might be the best alternative of all. Feel free to add it to your answer :)

Comment: Cascading a return status by passing it as a parameter makes the code less readable/maintainable... if you *really* need to do what the OP wants, do it, but document it!

Answer (score 0):

In a past project, I introduced a standard macro ER_CHK used throughout the project

Simplified for clarity, this is defined as:

```
#define ER_CHK(st) if (st != OK) {goto  EXIT;} else ;
```

You use it as follows:

```
status_t foo() {
   status_t  st;
   st = bar1(); ER_CHK(st);
   st = bar2(); ER_CHK(st);
   st = bar3(); ER_CHK(st);

   EXIT : ; // ER_CHK calls get here in case of non OK status
   if (st != OK) {
      // put exception handling code here
   }
}
```

This enforces a single, standard exit - leaving the real code very clean.

I actually define the macro to include a log where the failure was found: e.g.

```
#define ER_CHK(st) if (st != OK) {log(st,__FILE__,__LINE__); goto  EXIT;} else ;
```

this provides a log "traceback" as the stack unwinds.

The main point is that this is used throughout the entire project.
It allows the normal code to stand out, and there is a standard way to handle exceptions that can be viewed as an idiom,  pattern, or language extension.

It makes the normal (non-exception) code much more readable since

- there are fewer lines
- only relevant code is visible
- no need to distinguish between normal "ifs" and exception handling ifs.

For a fuller description see
https://forum.misra.org.uk/archive/index.php?thread-368.html
and a full article "Exception Handling in Embedded C Programs", C/C++ Users Journal,

Comment: All you seem to be doing here is hiding `goto` statements behind a macro. I'm not sure that's really addressing the OP's question. Also, can you explain the point of the empty `else ;` statement at the end of your macro?

Comment: While and if also hide gotos (or rather assembler jumps). The point is that pure c does not provide a primitive to finish the current function from multiple points so we are forced to flood the code with a series of if else. The ER_CHK is an invented primitive, that says continue at the EXIT label. (You could find a better name, but it is so idiomatic in the system, after every function that returns a status the shorter the name the cleaner the code. The else is to avoid issues when the macro is followed immediately by an else from a previous if. An alternative is do { goto...} while false.

Comment: You're right though, Im addressing the question inderectly, from a different angle.Misra is not a religion, its an attempt to improve code readability/etc. As I see it, the goal us to write readable code. Misra is a way to achieve that in many/most cases. If Misra has a coverage hole that forces me to write less readable code then my professional code of conduct  says that serving the reader/maintainer of the  code  is more important/critical than complicating the code to keep the peace with someone blindly  checking conformance.

Answer (score 0):

My poposal:

```
type do_stuff (void)
{
    type retval;
  
    retval = do_smth();
    if (retval == OK) {
        retval = do_smth2();
    }
    if (retval == OK) {
        retval = do_smth3();
    }
    return retval;
}
```

It seems more slow on case of (retval = KO) but... Compilers today are very smart. I'm quite sure that in a real compilation the function returns immediatly.
Furthermore, with MISRA, don't use goto and only one single return in every function.

Comment: *only one single return in every function* Never force algorithms into artificially-constrained, over-complex, hard-to-read patterns.

Comment: It is the same as previous response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66369712/12404603